# How WinRT Metro style HTML5/JavaScript applications are packaged and protected

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I’m just wondering how the HTML5/JavaScript Metro applications will be packaged and protected against reversal.

For packaging I’ll expect some sort of signed zip/jar (no mention about .appx on MSDN) but for protection, outside of heavy obfuscation for JavaScript I can’t envision any other way (maybe a new precompiled/binary format ?)

If the protection is not good, writing HTML5/JavaScript apps will not flourish too much IMHO.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of just crypto-obfuscation, another option is to implement the proprietary algorithms/logic inside of a 3rd party WinRT component. This way, you can have assurance that your proprietary algorithm is protected by virtue of being compiled. Granted if you choose to implement in .NET there is some ability by someone to reverse engineer it.

The idea is to write your client in JS/HTML5, presumably this would be somewhat straightforward in which you don't have a huge amount of proprietary info. Then you go write your WinRT component in C#/C++ which contains your proprietary "Sausage Manufacturing Process." You call into this WinRT component to create some "Sausage" with some data input. This approach means your secret recipe for Sausage is safe while still affording you the simplicity of the platform.

Is that a palatable solution?

Comment: So would this be a COM dynamically linked (!) sausage library? Or am I missing some new binding between JS and a C++ library?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're asking. Just as the Windows Runtime provides libraries with the OS itself, you can also write your own libraries and deploy them with your application.

The WinRT component could be written in C++ or C#. This would be deployed with the application and is callable in a natural manner, just as the 1st party Windows Runtime APIs are.

Comment: Sorry, got caught up in the metaphor.  I was just trying to figure out whether JS would be creating COM objects and using their methods and properties or using something new that lets JS code call into conventional non-COM libraries.

Comment: Well the Windows Runtime is similar to COM and as such, what I'm suggesting would allow JS to call into a native or managed code binary (C++ or C#) but the object would look just like a JS object with methods, properties, etc.


You would not be able to take "any old DLL" and stick it in there and package it up for use with JS. It needs to conform to the requirements laid out for constructing Windows Runtime components which include interface definitions, implementation of runtime classes as well as having metadata which JS can use to "understand" the object.

Comment: Thanks, that goes a long way toward illuminating the subject.

Comment: That is good to hear, please open another question if you require more illumination on the subject and I will comment at length along with other MSFT employees.

Comment: @ZacBrownMSFT I have no problem with C++/C# the quiestion relate to HTML5/JavaScript about how these will be protected against the reversing (actually viewing the code)

Answer (score 0):

i wondered the same thing and i agree that crypto-obfuscation is going to be key, certainly in the early days of protecting metro style apps.

apparently all code is going to be thoroughly reviewed on MS's side before it is offered for download, even obfuscated code, using code-scanning tools.  i guess how well this works remains to be seen.  i'm sure there'll be hiccups and security issues in the earlier days.

there's a fairly comprehensive guide to security here, which mentions 'guard rails' etc. which sound quite interesting.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27408

rob ganly

Comment: But think about out-of-Windows Store (or local/offline) distributed Metro apps ... How the code will be verified and secured ?

Comment: @devstonez There's no story for "out-of-Windows Store Metro apps" yet.

Comment: @pavel If you're looking to the BUILD sessions you may see that apps can be packaged for "local" consumption resulting an .appx, .cer and a bat for certificate registration.